# How to combine Regex strings

Tags: regex

I'm newbie for Regex, and i can't adapt other answers from similar answers.
I have two regex patern like these:

```
<tr bgcolor="\#ffcc66">(.*?)</t
```

and

```
<tr bgcolor="\#c9c9c9">(.*?)</t
```

So how can i combine these patterns?
Thanks...

Comment: that's not regex pattern. what do you want?

Comment: I want to take (.*?) including text

Comment: what can be inside ? number ? string? special char ? and what did you tried?

Comment: Anything. I am using this with php preg_match_all.

Comment: Are you trying to match either of them, or are you trying to match one of them followed by the other?

Comment: `<tr\s+bgcolor=(["']?).*?\1\s*>(.*?)<\/t`? Assuming any colour can be used

Comment: Thanks for your alternative answer. But i need to take only spesific colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match either of them, you can combine the parts that differ (the color codes) with `|`.  `pattern1|pattern2` matches either of the patterns.

```
<tr bgcolor="#(?:c9c9c9|ffcc66)">(.*?)</t
```

BTW, you don't need to escape `#`, it has no special meaning in regular expressions.

And if you need to extract the different color codes, leave out the `:?` that makes it a non-capturing group.

BTW, it's generally considered a poor idea to use regular expressions to parse HTML, you should use a DOM parser like `DOMDocument`.

Comment: Thank you. This solution is useful for me.